# Numpy H Stacking

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have these arrays:

```
co_ords = np.random.rand(10,2)
labels = np.random.choice(2,10)
```

which look like

```
array([[0.27195884, 0.95210374],
       [0.86416174, 0.88711233],
       [0.97141129, 0.22182439],
       [0.85683001, 0.85308369],
       [0.45731582, 0.24709513],
       [0.53758078, 0.90887869],
       [0.21484153, 0.86485449],
       [0.44954176, 0.82612431],
       [0.40761828, 0.6199162 ],
       [0.87705535, 0.40627418]])
```

and

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I want to combine them such that the label is included as the third member of the co-ordinate array as so :

```
array([[0.27195884, 0.95210374,1],
       [0.86416174, 0.88711233,1], ...
```

but I can't figure out the correct numpy manipulation to do this.

When I try

```
combined = np.hstack((co_ords,labels.T))
```

I get

```
array([0.27195884, 0.95210374, 0.86416174, 0.88711233, 0.97141129,
       0.22182439, 0.85683001, 0.85308369, 0.45731582, 0.24709513,
       0.53758078, 0.90887869, 0.21484153, 0.86485449, 0.44954176,
       0.82612431, 0.40761828, 0.6199162 , 0.87705535, 0.40627418,
       1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
       1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
       1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
       1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])
```

which is incorrectly flattened. What should I do instead?

Thanks!

Comment: `np.hstack([co_ords, labels[:,None]])`

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.concatenate`:

```py
import numpy as np

co_ords = np.random.rand(10, 2)
labels = np.random.choice(2, 10)


concatenated = np.concatenate((co_ords, labels.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1)
```

Edit:

For those who are interested: In this very scenario, `concatenate` seems to outperform `hstack`.

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import wraps
import time


def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def timeit_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f'Function {func.__name__} : {total_time:.4f} seconds')
        return result
    return timeit_wrapper


@timeit
def hs(runs):
    for i in range(runs):
        co_ords = np.random.rand(10, 2)
        labels = np.random.choice(2, 10)
        concatenated = np.hstack([co_ords, labels[:, None]])


@timeit
def concat(runs):
    for i in range(runs):
        co_ords = np.random.rand(10, 2)
        labels = np.random.choice(2, 10)
        concatenated = np.concatenate((co_ords, labels.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    concat(1_000_000)
    hs(1_000_000)
```

results in

```
Function concat : 6.8696 seconds
Function hs : 7.5453 seconds
```